# Why don't visual studio javascript breakpoints work in firebug?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, debugging, firebug

Why can't microsoft make setting a breakpoint in visual studio equivalent to adding the "debugger" keyword in javascript? I want to test javascript cross browser in a unified way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use debugger;

or Sys.Debug.assert() which will hit a debugger statement if assert fails

Answer (score 4):

Use the debugger keyword instead of setting breakpoints.. if the debugger is enabled, it will break...

```
debugger; //breakpoint here
```

As to why they don't work.  Firefox doesn't use the MS scrpting engine,so the VS debugger doesn't attach to Firefox.